# Ruby - convert 'array' to hash

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

How would you convert this: `"x[a=1,b=2,c=3]"`, which is a string, to a hash like `{ x => {'a'=>1, 'b'=>2, 'c'=>3} }` in ruby?

Comment: Do you mean a hash? Your example json object is not json. Also, that array doesn't look like an array. Please clarify what you are working with and what you want.

Comment: sorry, I meant hash. honestly, I dont know what to call the thing I'm trying to convert, but thats the format of it. I know, its awful.

Comment: How are you getting it? As a string? If so, you are asking how to parse that string into a hash, right?

Comment: yeah Im getting it as a string. yeah thats exactly what im trying to do

Comment: Do you want it a Hash or do you want it a string that looks like a hash? That's a very minimal example for input.

Comment: as a hash, not a string.

Comment: please provide more possibilities of input

Comment: basically any form similar to the one i posted. could be `string_of_some_sort[key=value, key=value, key=value, etc..]`.

Comment: is that still not enough? i dont know what else to say...

Comment: Usually it's best to post your best-effort attempt even if it's atrociously bad. There's no shame in trying.

Comment: The `x` in your expected output is not a string, just a bare `x`, what does that mean?  Also, you appear to have an array of key-value pairs `['a'=>1, ...]`; what does that mean?

Comment: that was my best attempt, honestly. thanks for improving it though. i appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

I assume the first key (`x`) should actually be a string.

```
def foo(str)
    key, rest = str.split("[")
    { key => Hash[rest.gsub("]","").split(",").map { |eqn| k, v = eqn.split("="); [k, v.to_i] }] }
end

foo("x[a=1,b=2,c=3]")
# => {"x"=>{"a"=>1, "b"=>2, "c"=>3}}
```

Comment: the devil's in the details. i did mean hash of key-value pairs. thanks for pointing that out

Comment: This is really a comment, but you could not have explained it with a comment's formatting limitations. It needed to be said, however, so +1.  Perer, alas, the question is still not clear. To get a helpful answer, you need to provide a context of where the string came from and how you intend to use the hash.